# R : Write CSV that has varying row values

Tags: r, csv, vector, dataframe

I am trying to write to a csv file from R, that has varying number of row values,

```
*for example*,
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,6
2,3
4,3,4,5
```

I have tried 3 possible attempts, but failed one way or the other.

1. I created a data frame that has 1 column, and I wrote each values separated as comma. However, it fails to be treated like a regular csv when I open it in editor, and there are issues when I am importing it in R through `read.table`

   forloop{

   row <- paste0("",row,",",value)

   }

   dataframe[i,] <- substring(row.temp,2)

2.I created a data frame that has missing values NA for values that are not present like,

```
t  NA w e NA
NA NA t q NA
```

And then I write to csv as

```
write.table(dataframe,file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE , col.names = FALSE, na = "", quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

But, I have unnecessary `,` for NA values

3. Pushing each row to a vector and writing to csv each row by row.

   forloop{

   row.temp <- c(row.temp,values)

   }
   write.table(temp,file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE , col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE, sep = ",")

But, the problem is each vector value is written to each new line.

I want to create this CSV file with the format through R. What approach could I take to solve this. I'm sure many people must have faced this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: I am using "arules " association library, and for read.transactions() method, it requires the CSV data to have that structure. I could not get the data.frame with NA values to work because each values should be unique (NA are duplicated).

Comment: @anz you're using `arules` in R? Can you please paste the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry, I did get the arules to recognize the csv where using approach #2. I wanted a cleaner csv file, and I want to avoid using another programming language just for that. I will require a cleaner version of this csv data later for publication and processing. I am yet to properly verify, but I think it's a bit slower . I did try a cleaner version by manipulating the csv file with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `cat`?  Just write the data you want directly to the output file line by line.

```
fileOut <- file("output.txt")
apply(dataframe, 1, function(x) {
                       l <- paste0(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=",")
                       cat(l, file=fileOut, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")

                    })
```

Note that I have `append` mode set to `TRUE`, to ensure that you don't overwrite the previous line during each iteration of `apply`.

This solution assumes that the data frame `dataframe` has, as you described in one of your attempts above, `NA` values in all columns which are missing values.  In this case, my snippet removes these `NA` values before writing to file.

Comment: I think I got the last row of the data frame only. It seems to have overwritten the previous rows.

Comment: @anz I was also having issues with `writeLines` for some reason.  Switching to `cat` seems to have gotten it working.

Comment: It's still writing the last row only even with cat. From cat documentation, append 
logical. Only used if the argument file is the name of file (and not a connection or "|cmd"). If TRUE output will be appended to file; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents of file.

Comment: This code worked for me when I tested it, and I got the CSV output along the lines of what you expect.  It sounds like `append=TRUE` mode is not working in your setup.

Comment: Well, append didn't work at my end. But I went with a similar approach as yours (as mentioned in #1 in my original post), of creating a string and outputting it to file. The issue with my initial approach was that I was concatenating "," in paste0() method instead of using sep="," . I guess this makes some sort of difference in file encoding and all. I created a dataframe of containing all these strings, and used write.table() to write to file. It worked. Thanks!! You certainly helped me find the bug that had me bugging for 5 hours. Cheers!!